# How do I disable Accounts all together?

Tags: account

I am building an app and don't need accounts. I simply need Contacts. What I cannot figure out is how to disable them, so "account" doesn't show up as a required field in my contact page layout.

Ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Contacts without Accounts are considered "private" and only the owner and sf admin can view them.  What you may want to look into is using Person Accounts instead.

Comment: I see. I haven't heard great things about Person Accounts, but I'll check them out.

Comment: This depends on your sharing model. It's possible to change things so that contacts without an account are visible to everybody in the company if desired from the Sharing Settings menu in the setup area.

Comment: I'm happy with Person Accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible; Contacts must be assigned to an Account. There are [various B2C options](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/225/which-b2c-option-to-choose), though they all just link Contacts and Accounts behind the scenes.