# How to hide shadow account in NPSP's 1:1 and 1:M model

Tags: managed-package, account, contact, account-management

Considering NPSP's 1:1 and 1:M model([Which B2C option to choose?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/225/which-b2c-option-to-choose)) what are the options to hide shadow/parent account in managed package (OWD for Account&Contact are Private). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you writing a package to specifically support the NPSP, or support it along with other data models? The NPSP "hides" the shadow account in the 1:1 model by overriding the detail page for those accounts with a VF page that redirects to the contact. The record itself is accessible in list views, Reports, etc. How else are you trying to hide it, and from whom?

Comment: I can control code in managed packaged and create list view, pages, etc that don't consider shadow accounts. But when this package is installed on client's environments it might happen that there are custom list views or other implementations that can show/expose these shadow accounts.

Comment: Right - that's as intended. What is the problem with these accounts being seen? Why do you need to hide them? One thing that is a problem in the NPSP is that ownership of the 1:1 account doesn't automatically follow the contact, so in Private OWD, that can be a problem. The current beta of the NPSP addresses this.